# Is this the normal behaviour of Cast<T> on Controls collection?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi guys I have found an issue that I'm unable to explain logically. In the following snippet flpRecordIndexes is a FlowLayoutPabel that contains lots of RecordIndexControl (a user control that I created). I want to delete everything except the first control. The same idea with flpRecordContainer.

If I execute this (without the ToList call), it only removes half of the controls, if it was a sequence for example it will remove (2,4,6,8) etc.

```
foreach (var recordIndexControl in flpRecordIndexes.Controls.Cast<RecordIndexControl>().Skip(1))
{
     flpRecordIndexes.Controls.Remove(recordIndexControl);
}
foreach (var recordControl in flpRecordContainer.Controls.Cast<RecordControl>().Skip(1))
{
     flpRecordContainer.Controls.Remove(recordControl);
}
```

If I execute this (with the ToList), it removes everything except the first control, what I wanted.

```
foreach (var recordIndexControl in    flpRecordIndexes.Controls.Cast<RecordIndexControl>().ToList().Skip(1))
{
      flpRecordIndexes.Controls.Remove(recordIndexControl);
}
foreach (var recordControl in flpRecordContainer.Controls.Cast<RecordControl>().ToList().Skip(1))
{
      flpRecordContainer.Controls.Remove(recordControl);
}
```

Why calling Cast without ToList produce this behavior?

Comment: You are modifying the list with the foreach, which is why it misses some controls.  The ToList is acting on a copy of the list.

Comment: Normally, a collection will throw an exception saying the collection has been modified while being enumerated. `ControlCollection` does not do that. It allows the removal of items.

Comment: I'd always use `Skip(1).ToList()` instead of `.ToList().Skip(1)`. The former produces a list which can also be accessed via index and is an in memory collection. The latter produces a LINQ query which uses deferred execution, so it's executed again and again if not consumed immediately(like you did).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is entirely normal, you are modifying the collection you are iterating with the Controls.Remove() call.  The Controls collection behaves different from other framework collections, it doesn't throw an exception when you do this.  So in effect you remove every other control, depending on the mix.

The ToList() call creates a copy of the Controls collection, it is no longer affected by the Remove() calls.  It is the correct workaround.

Do keep in mind that you most likely have a nasty leak.  The controls you remove *must* be disposed.  You can no longer rely on Winforms doing this for you, it can't since they are no longer in the Controls collection.  Failure to dispose them is a permanent leak, the garbage collector cannot help.

Comment: It's worth noting that `.Skip(1).ToList()` should be preferred over `.ToList().Skip(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why calling Cast without ToList produce this behavior?

Invoking `ToList()` materializes the collection, whereas `Cast<T>` does not. Once `ToList()` is invoked the list is solidified so to speak and you have a finite number in the list.

I would suggest iterating the [`Control.Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) via a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. This will avoid the issue you're seeing entirely and is actually more performant. The `ControlCollection` class inherits `IList` so you should be good with that.

```
for (var index = Controls.Count - 1; index >= 1; -- index)
{
    flpRecordContainer.Controls.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Note the `index >= 1` to ensure we leave the first control in the list.

Comment: Works only with a backwards loop ;)

Comment: I really liked this idea, but I couldn't mark more than one answer, you have my upvote.

Comment: You can always change the accepted answer - it's ultimately yours for the choosing, whichever answer best addresses your concerns.